# I want to show jQuery Loader before Value In another Drop down Loaded

Tags: jquery

> Here is my Code. What I am doing is when I select a value in the first
> dropdown value in Other dropdown is automatically fetched and selected
> from Database. But currently when I am selecting the first dropdown
> screen becomes inactive for some seconds and it becomes inactive when
> Value in second select List is Loaded. So what I want to do is I want
> to show loader before value in the second select list not gets loaded.
>
> Here is My Code :

```
function GetRefferalContactDetails(_AgencyId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SalesForce/GetReferralContactInfo',
                data: { agencyId: _AgencyId },
                cache: false,
                method: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        $("#ReferralInspectorId").html("");
                        $('#ReferralInspectorId').append($('<option>', {
                            value: '',
                            text: 'No Contacts to show'
                        }));
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#ReferralInspectorId").html("");
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            var fn = item.firstName || '';
                            var ln = item.lastName || '';
                            $('#ReferralInspectorId').append($('<option>', {
                                value: item.contactId,
                                text: fn + ' ' + ln
                            }));
                        });
                    }
                }
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use beforesend function to use loader
after complete loader can hide

```
    beforeSend: function() {
     $('#loader').show();
  },
  complete: function(){
     $('#loader').hide();
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Deferred object to show the Loader. Resolve the Deferrer object on success, reject in error.

Keep the code in calling method:

```
// Turn on the Loader
GetRefferalContactDetails(_AgencyId).done(function () {
// Turn off the Loader
});
```

Your method:

```
function GetRefferalContactDetails(_AgencyId) {
let deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SalesForce/GetReferralContactInfo',
                data: { agencyId: _AgencyId },
                cache: false,
                method: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == null) {
                        $("#ReferralInspectorId").html("");
                        $('#ReferralInspectorId').append($('<option>', {
                            value: '',
                            text: 'No Contacts to show'
                        }));
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#ReferralInspectorId").html("");
                        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                            var fn = item.firstName || '';
                            var ln = item.lastName || '';
                            $('#ReferralInspectorId').append($('<option>', {
                                value: item.contactId,
                                text: fn + ' ' + ln
                            }));
                        });
                    }
                   deferred.resolve();
                },
error: function () {
                deferred.reject();
            }
            })
        }
```

Note: ***async*** property also play role here. UI will be freezed when use your async: false, since jQuery is single threaded.
Use ***async: true,***. So that UI thread will be available to show the Loader.

Comment: I am getting Error of "deferred is not defined"

Comment: Check the scope of the variable (deferred) after the line:
let deferred = $.Deferred();

whether deferred object is undefined or not